# trying to log into correct database without password

Tags: mysql, permissions, mysql-5.6

My SQL 5.6.31 is setup on RHEL 7.2 as follows:

I can log in using the root user account as follows:

```
mysql -u root -p
Enter Password:
```

I created two normal users (one via my command line and one via my PHP based application)

**Normal User Created via Command Line:**

```
CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';
```

**Normal User Created via my PHP based Web App:**

My PHP Web app is just inserting the username into the database (database name: practiceDB) using INSERT INTO command in the code. Say for 
example normal user that got created and stored into the database has name `peter`

**Scenario #1:**

When I log in into the mysql from the command line using username `jeffery` and password `mypass` like the following:

```
mysql -u jeffery -pmypass
```

And run the command, `show databases`, I can see my `practiceDB` and other default MySQL databases like `information_schema`.

**Scenario #2:**

Since one of the normal user (`peter`) got created by the webapp and is residing in the database (practiceDB), I tried to access from the 
commandline the user without using any password as follows:

```
mysql -u peter
```

I can get into the mysql command prompt. Infact, forget about specifying the existing username `peter` in the above commandline. 
Even if I specify any thing , I can get into the command prompt. Also, when I checked `show databases`, I only saw only `information_schema` database
which is not where my user got stored.

Could anyone tell me why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `CREATE USER`, all it does is add a row to `mysql.user` with host set to `localhost`, `user` set to `jeffrey` or `peter`, and the password column is filled in. All the DB privileges are defaulted to `'N'`.

When you connect, run this:

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```

It will simply say `GRANT USAGE`. That means you can connect, AND NOTHING ELSE !!!

When you login as `root`, you must now explicitly tell mysqld to give grant privileges at various levels.

EXAMPLES

This will let jeffrey do everything except give away his privileges

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
```

This will let jeffrey do everything, including give away his privileges

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* to 'jeffrey'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

This will let jeffrey do everything inside a database called jeff

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON jeff.* to 'jeffrey'@'localhost';
```

Next time you login as `root`, run the following

```
DESC mysql.user;
DESC mysql.db;
```

This will show you what global (`mysql.user`) and database (`mysql.db`) privileges look like.

Please read [MySQL Documentation on all the grants you can give out to users](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html).

Comment: Thanks for answer. When I ran `SHOW GRANTS` after logging in as `root` user, I saw `Grants for root@localhost                                                                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*829353BIGPASSWORDHEREF977' WITH GRANT OPTION |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION `

Comment: Based on your answer, was it supposed to show `GRANT USAGE` only?

Comment: Yes. Doing `CREATE USER` does not give out any grants. So, `USAGE` is the only grant. You would have to execute GRANT commands on that new user thereafter.

Comment: Thanks. One more question. Suppose I am inserting a user into the database table from PHP , how can I make sure that the user shows up after running the command `select * from mysql.user; `. Right now only those users shows up which are created using `CREATE USER` command. Because of PHP related user insertion using `INSERT INTO DATABASE` command , I am unable to run grant command.